# How to prevent reloading the page using Menu component in ant design with typescript

Tags: typescript, antd, next.js13

```
<Menu
          style={{ textAlign: "left" }}
          mode="inline"
          items={items}
          defaultSelectedKeys={["dashboard"]}
          onClick={({ key }) => {
            if (key === " ") {
              // Do nothing
            } else {
              console.log(key);
              router.push(key, { scroll: false });
            }
          }}
        />
```

I tried to put an event.preventDefault() but it causes error